# ggplot bar graph - changing colour for value of y

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

im new to stackoverflow and need some help please. I wanted to colour y (Value) data above a level of 1.35 and cant seem to get it to work. wanted Steelblue for below 1.35 and plum for above 1.35. Below is working graph minus the colour change.

dataframe i have is

```
Timestamp  Value 
20/10/2021 1.56
21/10/2021 1.426
22/10/2021 1.344
23/10/2022 1.23
24/10/2022 1.11

water$Timestamp <- water$Timestamp %>% dmy
river <- ggplot() + 
  coord_cartesian() +
  layer(
    data = water,
    mapping = aes(x = Timestamp, y = Value),
    stat = "identity",
    geom ="point", 
    position = position_identity()
  ) +
  layer(
    data = riverwater,
    mapping = aes(x = Timestamp, y = Value),
    stat ="identity",
    geom ="line",
    position = position_identity()
  )
ggplotly(river)
```

---

This is the example of non continuous graph of the 2 plots, one line and other point
[image]

Comment: Just add `color = Value > 1.35` inside the `aes()` call.

Comment: Then you need to add `scale_color_manual(values=c("Steel blue","plum"))` to provide your custom colors.

Comment: thanks but i still get an error? Error in names(x) <- standardise_aes_names(names(x)) : 
  names() applied to a non-vecto

Comment: It looks like you are using two different datasets (`water` & `riverwater`) but you only shared one data snippet. Please share both datasets if the answer below doesn't address your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simulated some data here to help make a plot more like your real case.

To get the colors assigned by the `Value` you need to assign `color` inside `aes()`. `geom_line()` takes a `group` aesthetic which defines which data points are connected. If you specify a categorical aesthetic like `color = Value > 1.35` then the `group` aesthetic will inherit from there and split into 2 lines. If you want to connect all the data points, you simply have to set `group = 1` to specify that you want them all connected together.

There are a few stylistic things in your code I'd also suggest to change:

- It looks like you're plotting data from two separate `data.frames` into one graph. Usually it's better to `merge`/`rbind` those data somehow into a single `data.frame` before trying to incorporate into a single plot.
- Your {ggplot2} syntax is a bit unusual. Usually if you're using the same aesthetics in multiple layers it's more efficient to specify those within the `ggplot(aes(x = ..., y = ..., color = ...))` call to avoid repeating yourself. Also the layers are usually added by explicitly calling the `geom_*` or stat_*` of interest (as you can see in my code here). That said, your code is technically correct and will produce the desired plot with some small tweaks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(8)
d <- data.frame(Timestamp = seq(ymd("2021-10-20"), ymd("2022-10-24"), by = "days"),
                Value = 1.35 + cumsum(runif(370, -1, 1)))

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Timestamp, y = Value, color = Value > 1.35)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("Steel blue","plum"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you, how do i tidy up the syntax pls? i have tried below and not working. 
Also i have a larger DF not shown and how do i avoid using tibble?

p1 <- ggplot(data=water) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Timestamp, y = Value) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Timestamp, y = Value, color = Value > 1.35), stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "water") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Steel blue","plum")) +
  ggtitle("river water levels")
ggplotly(p1)

Comment: ok i worked out if i use d <- as_tibble(riverwater) i can get the data into a tibble. 
The graphs are not continuous and has separated based on colour? Do i need to use stat = "identity" to force them combine together?

Cant seem to add a photo either of the issue?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a `tibble` that's basically the same as a `data.frame` so don't worry about it. See updated answer.